# How do you use cURL to authenticate on a Rails application that uses Devise?

Tags: curl, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to test my rails web service using cURL, yet so far I could only do it while deactivating `before_filter :authenticate_user!`. But I'd like to log in a priori and then create, destroy etc.

I saw that with cURL you can authenticate and save the session info in a cookie, that you use for your following requests, yet I couldn't make it work with Devise: in my scenario, the user logs in using an email/password combination, so I'm trying:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -d 'email=email@example.com&password=password' \
  -c cookie \
  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in > out
```

and I get: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise/sessionsController#create`

Could somebody give me an idea / an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works:

**Authenticate:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in \
  -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'test@example.com', 'password' : 'password'}}" \
  -c cookie
```

**Show:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X GET http://localhost:3000/pages/1.xml \
  -b cookie
```

Comment: This works for GET requests, however, for POST requests it does not appear to work.

Comment: That might be because you need a CSRF token for non-GET requests in Rails 3 (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: The authentication stepped worked for me after I switched the single and double quotes, but was not able to access anything.

Comment: I am using memcached-based sessions and it appears that Rails is not sending back a session id in a cookie when I use the above curl. I can tell that it will work *if* there was a cookie, but that's not happening. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 4):

This is because Rails by default adds an authenticity token to forms to protect from malicious forgery of submitted parameters. As you do not supply this token with your request, rails does not accept it.
You can bypass this with

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

in your controller, where authorization takes place, better even to limit it to the authorization action with :only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this (not tested):

```
curl --user name:password http://www.domain.com
curl --user name:password -f 'key=value' http://www.domain.com
```

Comment: Sending the parameters like that doesn't satisfy the given scenario either.

Answer (score 1):

Got the following [answer from José Valim](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/779):

> If you have an web service, sign in
>   should be done using HTTP Auth. If
>   not, your option is to disable
>   authenticity token on the session
>   form, although not recommended.