# curling Devise ends up in redirect loop

Tags: curl, devise

I am trying to hit my Rails app with curl but keep ending up in a redirect loop. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673027/how-do-you-use-curl-to-authenticate-on-a-rails-application-that-uses-devise) which helped me build the correct curl.

The problem is that even though the initial curl authenticates correctly, I end up in a redirect loop, being sent back to the login page. I am using memcached for my session store and I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Comment: What's your code, is the curl handle storing cookies and sending them on subsequent requests?

Comment: @drew010 I am passing the -c option to curl but it seems like the cookie file isn't being created. When I inspect the headers coming back from my app I don't see a 'Set-Cookie' header being passed back. I'm wondering if maybe I need to mess with the User-Agent?